# Can ONLY connect to ports http:80 and https:443?

Tags: networking, port, timeout

I have a problem where I can only connect to the standard http port 80 and https port 443. I can access websites perfectly and play videos and all, but when I try to connect to IP's using other ports, such as the ports used by internet game servers like Agar.io and Steam, the connection times out and I can't connect or I have to try many times to connect to the server.

This problem has came up only a few days ago, when my family and I returned to Australia from our 4 week holiday. Before, everything was working fine, instant connection to everything. I have tried contacting Telstra numerous times, and they have told me they couldn't help, and to find third-party assistance. They did say something about setting up our port connections properly though. I can do Tracerts and Telnets on the IP's or add some consoles from Agar.io if you really need it. I would really appreciate if you could help me fix this problem.

Info:

System Specs- http://pastebin.com/KavhNWQ6

MiniToolBox log- http://pastebin.com/QmahpXZe

Connection: Ethernet Cable from wall to Laptop

Router: Netgear Wireless Cable Gateway CG3100D-2BPAUS

Type of Internet: Cable

Comment: Could it be that they "upgraded" your connection to IPv6 with DualStack-Lite IPv4-access?

Comment: Have you tried disabling your firewall to see if this eliminates the problem? if it does, you may want to check your outbound rules

Comment: @Harvey I have tried disabling my Windows firewall, but that didn't do anything. I also have made an inbound and outbound rule for Chrome, and made an Inbound and Outbound rule for all local ports.

Comment: @TJJ What does that mean, how do I check, and what do I do to fix it if it is IPv6?

Comment: I know it's pretty straight-foward but two things, have you rebooted your router? and if so have you fully reset it. (i.e. changed back to factory settings). Do you get this issue on all other devices connected to your router?

Comment: @Harvey yeah, i have rebooted and fully reset to factory settings. I am currently on factory settings for the router now. All devices in my house are experiencing this problem.

Comment: Could you try using a free VPN service such as tunnel bear. This will rule out the possibility of your ISP restricting you

Comment: @Harvey I will try that, but before I do that, I'll tell my ISP to change the DNS server they have assigned me, because I have a dynamic i.p, and the DNS I used to have has probably been reset since I left my power off for so long.

Comment: You could just change it yourself on your router, try Google's DNS server 8.8.8.8. Way quicker than calling your ISP

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the antivirus software and the firewall to have a troubleshoot.

Untick all the proxy configurations.
Internet Explorer\Tools\Internet Options\Connections\LAN settings

Comment: I have unticked everything, including the "automatically detect settings" option.